Why is my custom.rc file not executing frida-server while it is being executed?
I am trying to run frida-server on boot on LDplayer Android 9. For this I found this post
I have used the INIT method and created a custom.rc file:
    #/etc/init/custom.rc

# execute the binary when boot is completed
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    write /data/local/tmp/here.txt here
    exec_background u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/frida-server

The device is rooted, Frida-server is CHMODded 755, SElinux SetEnforce is 0, and after I reboot I can see the here.txt file. So the RC file is being executed.
However, frida-server is not starting. I have no idea where to go from here.

Solved!
When using just:
exec_background -- /system/bin/frida-server 

The process starts and is running.
